# Create abstract complexType as an input to an operation for webservice argument class - Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-9

I ran into the error:

```
 Unable to create web service argument class [Lcom.verticalresponse.api._1_0.VRAPI_xsd.NVPair;. Error: java.lang.InstantiationException: [Lcom.verticalresponse.api._1_0.VRAPI_xsd.NVPair;. Often this is because the web service defines an abstract complexType as an input to an operation. You must create an actual instance of this type in Java.
```

while trying to call a WebService.  And I have the solution now and I want to post it for anyone else who might be in my situation one day. The issue is that you have to pass a complex structure through coldfusion to the webservice and it doesn't always like to play well.

The answer to this conundrum is how you set up the data as a combination of structures and arrays.

you have to build the data in a very particular manner.

```
    <cfscript>
        var ELMResults = StructNew();
        var ELMArgs = StructNew();
        var MemberData = arrayNew(1);   
        var ListMember = StructNew();
                    var session_id = 'the_session_id_provided'
        var list_id = 'the_list_id_provided';
        var list_name = 'the_list_name_provided';
        var list_type = 'the_list_type_provided';



        /* set session id */
        ELMArgs.session_id = session_id;

        /* set member data */
        MemberData[1] = StructNew();
        MemberData[1].name = "hash";
        MemberData[1].value = hash_value;

        MemberData[2] = StructNew();
        MemberData[2].name = "optin_status";
        MemberData[2].value = "2";

        MemberData[3] = StructNew();
        MemberData[3].name = "first_name";
        MemberData[3].value = "Chewbacca";

        MemberData[4] = StructNew();
        MemberData[4].name = "fax";
        MemberData[4].value = "1112223333";

        MemberData[5] = StructNew();
        MemberData[5].name = "email_address";
        MemberData[5].value = email_address;


        /* set list member details */
        ListMember.list_id = list_id;
        ListMember.list_name = list_name;
        ListMember.list_type = list_type;
        ListMember.member_data = MemberData;
        ELMArgs.list_member = ListMember;
        ELMResults = VR.editListMember(ELMArgs);
    </cfscript>
```

I hope this helps someone because I was scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question and posted it here with the question because I couldn't post an answer on the same day of asking the question.  I am now simply closing out the thread.  I hope this answer helps someone because I was scratching my head for a while with this one.

Cheers, JP